# r expression works in ddply() in R, but not in shiny markdown

Tags: r, plyr, r-markdown

I'm having a strange problem I can't solve.

the following code works fine in R studio:

```
> set.seed(12345)
> 
> library(plyr)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> dt <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=sample(1:3, 10, replace=T))
> 
> var <- "a"
> formula <- parse(text=paste0(var, "+1"))[[1]]
> 
> print(dt)
    a b
1   1 3
2   2 3
3   3 3
4   4 3
5   5 2
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 2
9   9 3
10 10 3
> 
> # this works in R Studio, but not in markdown
> res <- dt %>%
+     ddply(.(b), transform, diff = eval(formula))
> print(res)
    a b diff
1   6 1    7
2   7 1    8
3   5 2    6
4   8 2    9
5   1 3    2
6   2 3    3
7   3 3    4
8   4 3    5
9   9 3   10
10 10 3   11
```

When I run the same code in a R markdown, I get an error message saying

```
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0
```

What's going on here? Here is my markdown code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "8/29/2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
set.seed(12345)

library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=sample(1:3, 10, replace=T))

formula <- parse(text=paste0("a", "+1"))[[1]]

#this does work in R, but not in markdown
res <- dt %>%
    ddply(.(b), transform, diff = eval(formula))
res


```
````

Thanks

Comment: can't reproduce. The result on my machine is the very same as presented above.

Comment: did you run the last block of code in a markdown document? The code runs in r studio, just not in a r markdown.

Comment: @chungkim721 I took your code, saved to file, run the thing with `rmarkdown::run` in RStudio and was able to access the app via localhost in Chrome. Did you deploy on a server, or what exactly do you mean by "in r markdown"?

Comment: This looks like a bug of shiny runtime. rmarkdown works fine.

Comment: If you're using `eval(parse(...))`, there's usually a better way. See `fortunes::fortune(106)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who commented on my post.

First off, I'm not sure why @nilsole was able to run the r markdown part of the code fine and I wasn't. I ran the markdown on my company's server, so maybe it has to do with our server? My utter lack of knowledge on the subject renders me unable to even guess where the cause might be.

Secondly, this is the response we received from Winston Chang when we contacted RStudio.

> Sorry, I don't know the exact cause of the problem. It looks like the
>   shiny runtime is doing something with the environment that ddply and
>   transform aren't expecting. Both of those use non-standard evaluation
>   of their arguments, and when combined with eval, the results are
>   unpredictable. It's not completely clear to me in which environment
>   the eval() will run. This will work, because the function captures the
>   calling environment: ddply(dt, .(b), function(x) {   mutate(x, diff =
>   eval(f)) })
>
> In general, it would be safer to stick with dplyr and its versions of
>   functions that use standard evaluation of arguments. For example: dt
>   %>%   group_by(b) %>%   mutate_(diff = "a+1")

both of whose recommendations solve my problem.